# ¿Input select con restriccion en laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tengo un select mediante en el cual listo a todos los usuarios registrados del sistema, me doy cuenta que solo necesito a los usuarios **que no sean administradores**. ¿Como podría agregar esta restricción a mi controlador?. Aclaro que esoy utilizando el paquete laravel/permission
En el metodo create estoy pasando en una variable a todos los usuarios,

Controllador

```
 public function create()
    { 
        $order = new Order();      

        $this->authorize('create', $order);

        return view('admin.orders.partials.form', [
            'clients'   => Client::all(),
            'users'     => User::all(),
            'products'  => Order::pluck('name_product', 'name_product'),
            'order'     => $order
        ]);  


    }
```

tabla roles
[image: roles]

tabla model-has-roles
[image: model_has_roles]

Como se puede observar en las imágenes deseo no mostrar al model_id 3 ya que tiene el rol de administrador, ¿Hay alguna manera de poner un where  en mi método create de mi controlador donde relaciones a la tabla user, roles y model_has_roles, para traer a los usuarios que cumplan con la condición solicitada?

**ACTUALIZADO**

Esta es mi tabla users no hay ningún campo que guarde el id del rol que le pertenece al usuario.

[image: users]

Este es mi modelo de usuario acá agrego el trait hasRole

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    use HasRoles;
}
```

Comment: No conozco el paquete que mencionas, parece que arma una relación polimórfica de los modelos con los roles. Como haces para acceder a esa relación desde User? Pregunto porque con la relación podrías usar `whereDoesntHave('roles' .... ('Id', 1)` https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence

Comment: @porloscerros Ψ gracias por tu pronta respuesta actualice mi pregunta voy a intentar lo que me indicaste hace un momento.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ estoy intentando lo que me indicas, y no me sale no tengo mucho conociemiento en laravel, creo que  es como  mencionaste hace un momento arma una relacion polimorfica con los modelos, la informacion esta en la tabla model_has_role, ya que el campo model_id corresponde al usuario con id 3, y el campo role_id  corresponde al rol administrador que pertenece a la tabla rol, me podrías ayuda en con esta consulta?

Comment: Si no me equivoco, esta es la librería [documentación](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/basic-usage/basic-usage/), realmente no la tengo instalada para probar, veo que para hacerlo por Eloquent, habría que estudiar un poco más como trabaja la librería internamente como para usar `whereDoesntHaveMorph` si fuese el caso. Hice una búsqueda rápida y encontré esto que parece ser lo mismo que preguntas [get users has not role X](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/issues/1037)

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ  Gracias me fue muy útil tu respuesta!!!!